# Bulk Unlock Netsuite Records

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I have a series of NetSuite Transactions that have been locked by a workflow. I've since modified the workflow so that it does not lock future records when accessed by certain users.

However, I'm having trouble unlocking records that have *already been locked* by this workflow.  I need them unlocked (for at least my ETL user) to access them for an ETL job I have running.  I've found Netsuite's documentation extremely sparse and unclear when it comes to record locks.

I have two questions around this:

(1) Is it possible to unlock records in Netsuite?

(2) Is it possible to bulk unlock records in Netsuite?  I've been looking for an API call that will list out all locked records and allow me to update them using my new workflow, but haven't had any luck so far.

Answer (score 1):

Workflows usually work with different states of records, if you have locked records in any state, when yu edit your workflow and delete or inactive the step of lock records, all locked records should become available.

Answer (score 1):

Just put a condition statement in the workflow to bypass the lock for your user.

Comment: Is it possible to set up a workflow that automatically unlocks *any* locked record for a specific user, then locks the record when that user is done?